# Hi there guys I want to choose a random php function at runtime between 1-5 display the result of the array processing for the given array

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

In this sub‐task, you will code a variable function. A PHP array function is
selected at runtime and executed on an array of numbers. In order to choose a function
at runtime, a random number is generated between 1 and 5. For each random number a
specific function is executed for the given array of numbers. The five array
functions that you must use are shuffle(), sort(), rsort(), array_pop() and
array_reverse(). Display the random number generated and the result of the array
processing for the given array. Use an array with values 6, 98, 54, 13, 25, 70.

This is a practice question and this I what I got so far.

```
    <?php
function a(){  
    echo shuffle($array); 
}
function b(){  
    echo sort($array);
}
function c(){  
    echo rsort($array);
}
function d(){ 
    echo array_pop($array);
}
function e(){  
    echo array_reverse($array);
}
$variableFunction = array('6', '98', '54', '13', '25', '70');
call_user_func($variableFunction[array_rand($variableFunction)]);
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Okay, so `$variableFunction` actually contains the *values* from the question. But you need to select a random *function* (one of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` or `e` -- `f` is the same as `e` and the assignment only wants five options). Once you have that you need to tell these functions what `$array` is (you'll want to read up on [function arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) and checkout the docs for [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/call_user_func)) and after you have it working, you still need to adhere to the "Display the random number generated" part of the question

Comment: I'm so stressed I didn't even see that e and f were the same . Thanks, I'm still working on it tho.

Comment: I put this together as an example for you. maybe it will help. https://www.tehplayground.com/9fK4t9BtKCk5QYzD

Comment: ok thanks imma take a look